# API Ajax structuring

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My goal: Implement a search function to show nutritional data pulled from USDA NDB API.

Status: Partial Success

The problem: USDA stuctured the object returned somewhat obnoxious. Referincing this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE1ZP.jpg 
Pizza has water at the first key value and Milk has energy.

My Question:

If I want to obtain the energy for example for all searches, how would I structure my ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: 'http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=' + ndbno[0] + '&type=b&format=json&api_key=',
        success: function(results) {
            food0 = results.report.food;
            console.log(food0);
            $("#jsGrid-nutrition").jsGrid("insertItem", {
                name: food0.name,
                kCal: food0.nutrients[1].measures[0].value,
                servingSize: food0.nutrients[1].measures[0].label,
                quantity: food0.nutrients[1].measures[0].qty,
                carbs: food0.nutrients[4].value + food0.nutrients[4].unit,
                fats: food0.nutrients[3].value + food0.nutrients[3].unit,
                saturatedFats: food0.nutrients[3].value + food0.nutrients[3].unit,
                protein: food0.nutrients[24].value + food0.nutrients[24].unit
            });
```

Comment: loop over the array and look for energy?

Comment: You could use the jquery grep function to find the energy: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop your array and search for specific `name`:

```
var energy = '';

$.each(food0.nutrient, function () {
    if (this.name == 'Energy') {
        energy = this.value;

        return false; // == break; return true == continue;
    }
});
```